# Wpf ComoBox Selected Item Alignment

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, styles

Hi i'm using [Reuxables Free Theme Inc](http://www.nukeation.com/free.aspx#5) in my wpf application.

I added the theme to App.xaml this way:

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/ReuxablesLegacy;component/inc.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And in my Main.xaml i used a combobox by default its content aligned to the left:

[image]

I want to align the content of combobox to right.

When i tried `HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"` nothing changed.

I tried `TextBlock.TextAlignment="Right"` and the result is this:

[image]

This time comboboxitems are aligned to the right however selected item which is "1" in this picture, is still aligned to the left.

Whatever i tried i couldn't align the selected item to the right. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does *i couldn't align the selected item alignment to the right* actually mean?

Comment: In 2nd image selected item which is "1" is not aligned to the right. How can align it to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look on the [ComboBox Styles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN, you will find the default `ControlTemplate` for the `ComboBox` used in WPF. It's too large to display here, but if you look down the page, you'll see a `TextBox` control named `PART_EditableTextBox` which looks like this:

```
  <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
           Style="{x:Null}"
           Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
           Margin="3,3,23,3"
           Focusable="True"
           Background="Transparent"
           Visibility="Hidden"
           IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
```

This is the control used for the selected value and as you can see, its `HorizontalAlignment` property is hard coded to `"Left"`, so text in this `TextBox` will always align to the left.

Therefore, to align text to the right, you will need to define your own `ControlTemplate` for your `ComboBox`. You can find out how to do that in the [Control Authoring Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN. Basically, you just need to copy the default `ControlTemplate` and replace the `TextBox` above with the `TextBox` below:

```
  <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
           Style="{x:Null}"
           Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
           HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
           Margin="3,3,23,3"
           Focusable="True"
           Background="Transparent"
           Visibility="Hidden"
           IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
```

Once you have done this and applied your new `ControlTemplate` to the `Template` property of your `ComboBox` and set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to `Right`, then you should finally see your selected value text align to the right.

Comment: I am using an old theme (Expression Dark) and I found that I also had to modify the "HorizontalAlignment" of the ContentPresenter above it to get it to work.